# Defining cyclic codes

Tags: coding-theory

> Let C be the cyclic code defined by a primitive nth root of unity.

This is the start of a question I have been given, but I don't understand how this is a valid way to define a cyclic code. The way I learnt to define them is by giving a generating function for the code.

Now clearly given a primitive nth root of unity it is possible to find a minimal polynomial which it satisfies. Is that what the question means? That the generating function is just this?

Comment: Correct. That minimal polynomial is a factor of $x^n-1$, and thus acts as a generator polynomial for a cyclic code of length $n$.